# Writing to SDCARD problem in Android?

Tags: java, android, buffer

When implementing download function it work but during file saving to sdcard i get the following

Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.

Also  IO Exception occure

W(14495:0x389f) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard
W(14495:0x389f)         at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:244)
W(14495:0x389f)         at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:97)
W(14495:0x389f)         at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:168)
W(14495:0x389f)         at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:147)

Comment: I like how this question puts the warning first as though it's most important, and then tacks on the exception as an afterthought.

Comment: i see you should comment if you can help or advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you get the File object by calling

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Also if you app is using 1.6+ you will need the [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission. If that doesn't help, post the code.

Comment: I have use BufferedInput stream 

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(objectComplete.getDataInputStream());
      
BufferedOutputStream bos = new 
BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/sdcard"));
int i;
while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
bos.write(i);
System.out.println("Writing file");
}
System.out.println("Greeting:");

also i have set permission to writiong on sdcard
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @Ahmed Salem: Please read the answer you were given. It does not match your code. Your code hardwires `"/sdcard"`. That is not a valid path on all Android devices. You will notice that BrennaSoft's answer does not hardwire `"/sdcard"`, but rather uses `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Modify your code to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, and you may have better luck.

Comment: @CommonsWaree
i have change code and still have exception 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard